# OpenGL: Orbiting with Orthogonal projection

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm modelling the solar system and testing the orbit of the Earth around the Sun, using orthogonal projection.

The starting point of the Earth is to the right of the Sun, direction of moving is to the left hand side. But the Earth is not completely rendered when it is in front of the Sun and when go further behind the Sun, as you can see from 3 images below:

Starting point:

[image]

Next frame:

[image]

Final frame:

[image]

Can some one explain what exactly happening here? I think this is the cull face problem, I tried:

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACES);
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
```

It doesn't work actually.

This is my code:

```
// global vars
int width = 1820, height = 960;
#define CENTRE_X static_cast<float>(width/2)
#define CENTRE_Z static_cast<float>(-height/2)
#define EARTH_SIZE glm::vec3(30.0f, 40.0f, 30.0f)
#define SUN_SIZE EARTH_SIZE*3.0f

void renderSun(int i){
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_ID[0]);
    glUniform1i(texture_Location, 0);
    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<float>(width), 0.0f, static_cast<float>(height), 0.0f, 100.0f);
    glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(0, 120, 1),
        glm::vec3(0, 0, 0),
        glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)
    );

    /* Animations */
    GLfloat angle = (GLfloat) (i);
    View = glm::translate(View, glm::vec3(static_cast<float>(width/2), 0.0f, static_cast<float>(-height/2)));
    View = glm::scale(View, SUN_SIZE);
    View = glm::rotate(View, angle * 0.5f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    /* ******* */
    glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model;

    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mvpMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numsToDraw, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void renderEarth(int i){
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_ID[3]);
    glUniform1i(texture_Location, 0);
    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<float>(width), 0.0f, static_cast<float>(height), 0.0f, 100.0f);
    glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(0, 150, 1),
        glm::vec3(0, 0, 0),
        glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)
    );

    /* Animations */
    GLfloat angle = (GLfloat) (i);
    View = glm::translate(View, glm::vec3(cos(orbitPos)*150, sin(orbitPos)*150, 0.0f));
    View = glm::translate(View, glm::vec3(CENTRE_X, 0.0f, CENTRE_Z));
    View = glm::scale(View, EARTH_SIZE);
    View = glm::rotate(View, angle * 0.5f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    /* ******* */
    glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    orbitPos += 0.005;
    glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model;

    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mvpMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numsToDraw, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: In the first translation in `renderEarth`, should the y and z values be switched?

Comment: It appears you are not rotating the earth around the sun, you are manipulating the `View` matrix to achieve the rotation. However, you're not applying the same view matrix to both the earth and the sun, so presumably they are intersecting within clip space. Use a consistent `View` matrix, and modify the `Model` matrix for the earth and the sun.

Comment: @bwroga my Z-axis is pointing upwards

Comment: @MuertoExcobito can you show me how can I rewrite those two method in a proper way please?

Answer (score 1):

You are using inconsistent `View` matrices, your code is essentially rotating the view of the earth, which causes it to move relative to the sun. This is very unusual way to do things, and is probably the cause of your problems. It is (presumably) causing the models to collide in clip space, and intersect with one another. You should instead use the same `View` matrix for both, and modify the `Model` matrix for the earth model. Keeping the `renderSun` method the same, you could do this by modifying `renderEarth`:

```
void renderEarth(int i){
//...
/* Animations */
GLfloat angle = (GLfloat) (i);
glm::mat4 M0 = glm::translate(View, glm::vec3(cos(orbitPos)*150, sin(orbitPos)*150, 0.0f));
glm::mat4 M1 = glm::translate(View, glm::vec3(CENTRE_X, 0.0f, CENTRE_Z));
glm::mat4 M2 = glm::scale(View, EARTH_SIZE);
glm::mat4 M3 = glm::rotate(View, angle * 0.5f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
/* ******* */
orbitPos += 0.005;
glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * M3 * M2 * M1 * M0;
// ...
```

Comment: I was able to fix it :) Also, it's not passing the View, I did this, and I think im more correct: `glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    Model = glm::translate(Model, glm::vec3(CENTRE_X, 0.0f, CENTRE_Z));
    Model = glm::translate(Model, glm::vec3(cos(earthOrbitPos)*250, 0.0f, sin(earthOrbitPos)*250));
    Model = glm::scale(Model, EARTH_SIZE);
    Model = glm::rotate(Model, angle * 0.5f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    earthOrbitPos += 0.005;`